# Create a Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc instance from a Zend_Controller_Request

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I have pages in my application that make up the navigation tree.  I would like to dynamically insert pages into my navigation using the values of the request.  I already have the logic to find the page and then call the `addPage()` method on it.  What I'm looking for is how to easily pass the `Zend_Controller_Request` values to `Zend_Navigation_Page::factory()` so I can add that page.  Maybe even written as a plugin?

---

**Solution**

AngelP got the closest, so I'm giving him credit, but here's my solution:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($page = $this->view->siteNav->findBy('id', $page_id)) {
    $page->addPage(Zend_Navigation_Page::factory($request->getParams())
            ->setParams($request->getParams())
            ->setLabel($this->view->title)
            ->setVisible(false));
}
```

This code is executed from a controller action.  `$this->view->siteNav` is an instance of `Zend_Navigation` that I have in the view.  `getParams()` from the `Zend_Controller_Request` instance is easily passed to `Zend_Navigation_Page::factory()` and then to the `setParams()` method of the `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have limited resources at the moment so I cannot really check my suggestion, but if you're in you controller, why don't you..

```
$controller = $this->_request->getControllerName();
$action = $this->_request->getActionName();

$page = new Zend_Navigation_Page( array(
                   'label' => "Sonny's Page",
                   'controller' => $controller,
                   'action' => $action
));
```

Maybe you could use this as a plugin so that you overload your view? And then add to your Navigation Container?

Cheers,
Angel

Comment: I'm aware of how to build a `Zend_Navigation_Page` by using a manually built key => value array, but was hoping there was some shortcut by using some methods from the `Zend_Controller_Request`

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know the code you have written already, I'm only guessing…

You need to:

- retrieve the actual Zend_Navigation container used in `navigation()` view helper
- create new Zend_Navigation_Page instance from array of data retrieved from the request
- add the page to the container
- assign the new container to the navigation helper

This should be easy. The rest you need to know:

- how to write controller plugin with `preDispatch` method, and put the above there,
- how to access current view instance in this plugin (from the view renderer or from application resource/bootstrap)

Then in the plugin you operate on navigation view helper as usual in the view.

Hope this clarified some things.

Comment: From the "You need to:" list I have steps 1, 3, and 4 all worked out.  It was hoping for a simple way to create a `Zend_Navigation_Page` instance from methods in the `Zend_Controller_Request` instance that's available in a controller action by calling `$this->getRequest()`.

Comment: @Sonny AngelP Described step 2 in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389358/create-a-zend-navigation-page-mvc-instance-from-a-zend-controller-request/4391789#4391789).

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the instance in Zend_Registry and then in a postDispatch from either a plugin, module bootstrap or action controller add the pages to the original nav?

Comment: I'm not following your answer.  I have the `Zend_Navigation` instance set in a view variable.  I don't have a problem with that part.  I want to add the pages in specific controller actions, and I already know how to accomplish that part as well.  What I don't know is how to simply create a `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc` instance using the `Zend_Controller_Request`.